# I want to trigger OnScrollChangeListener for certain space scrolled

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-scrollview

I have a scrollView that needs to hide a keyboard when I drag certain Y offset , currently it will always close my keyboard when I enter an edittext but what I want to do is to execute the hideKeyboard() when for example the view has been scrolled Y units

```
binding.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { view, i, i2, i3, i4 ->
            hideKeyboard()
        }
```

I want to add a condition like this

```
binding.scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { view, i, i2, i3, i4 ->
            if(position_dragged_in_Y > some_value)
            hideKeyboard()
        }
```

How do I do this ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting an `OnScrollChanceListener`, I got the following attributes:

```
    scrollview.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
    }
```

So, `OnScrollChangeListener` already gives us the current Position of the scrollY Position. To set a condition like (if `scrollY` >= `someYPosition`), you could add an invisible View inside your scrollview, like this:

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/myInvisibleViewForCondition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then, to get the absolute Y Position of our `myInvisibleViewForCondition` we use the following extension function:

```
fun View.getLocationOnScreen(): Point {
    val location = IntArray(2)
    this.getLocationOnScreen(location)
    return Point(location[0],location[1])
}
```

Now we can start to work on the condition:

```
    scrollview.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
        val absolutPositionOfInvisibleView = myInvisibleViewForCondition.getLocationOnScreen()
        val yPositionOfInvisibleView = absolutPositionOfInvisibleView.y
        if (scrollY > yPositionOfInvisibleView) {
            hideKeyboad()
        }
    }
```

I couldn't test the functionality, so let me now, if this works.

Cheers